# Pagebreaks for tables

Tags: javascript, html

This is the structure of user's HTML input:

```
<body>
 <div id="main">

  <div id="extra">
   <table></table>
  </div>
   <div id="extra">
   <table></table>
  </div>
  <div id="extra">
   <table></table>
  </div>
  <!-- more divs --> 

 </div>
</body>
```

What I need to do is to display this structure divided **in pages**, like Microsoft Word does. Due to the unpredictable size of the content (tables), part of a table could possibly overflow from a page after data's been uploaded, so this overflowed part should move to the next page.

See this sketch:

[image: content divided in pages]

Comment: You have a lot of context, but basically your question seems to come down to: *"How do I detect where a page-break will be in `print` media, and adjust my `screen` media CSS accordingly?"*, right?

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks, that's true, and the content is "table" should be emphasized. I asked simplified problems before but seems no body answers, or just give simple solutions for character content. So I decided to make a detailed description.

Comment: This is not trivial,  HTML is not a print medium, you will need to calculate by your content when you need to make a pagebreak.  HTML will not be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to come down to (rephrased):

> How do I detect where a page-break will be in `print` media, and adjust my `screen` media CSS or even HTML accordingly?

As far as I know, you cannot quite do this.

The "easy" workaround would be to guesstimate where page breaks occur and insert needed classes / elements at those locations.

A "harder" but little more finegrained solution would be to use Javascript to parse the DOM and do a slightly more precise guesstimation.

In any case, you can't be 100% precise (as in Word), because there are outside factors that you can't see or control from within your page, like the printer's properties, browser settings on whether or not to print headers and footers, etc.